# Transpose data in excel with looping

Tags: excel, vba, loops, transpose

I am trying to transpose/reformat the data in a report using VBA to copy the employee Name to a new sheet and then copy the count of missed punches, Late in, Late out etc to columns with those headers.  The trick is the variable rows depending on is that employee had no timecard issues or if that had several different varieties of timecard issues.

This report can vary in length but there is a "Grand Total" in column A that could trigger the loop to stop.  There is blank cell in between each Employee chunk that could trigger a do until loop to move to column H and find the count of each issue listed.

Input:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Appreciate any help!

I have tried experimenting with PasteSpecial Transpose but my issue is getting a loop to start with cell B43 and having it pull the Name, Paste in new sheet, then copy and pasting any timecard issues into columns on next page.

Comment: You will need a bank of names to refer to- otherwise how do you expect VBA to know the difference between a name and some other string

Comment: The name is the first string in each block of information. So There is always a blank cell above it.  I figured that would be how I identified each name for the looping  Considering employees will churn over time, maintaining a list is not ideal for the solution I am seeking.

Comment: Do until loop should help then

Comment: *'having it pull the Name, Paste in new sheet, then copy and pasting any timecard issues into columns on next page'* makes no sense according to the supplied images. You need to show some effort and describe the **specific problem** you are having. It might be possible to decipher your dilemma from there.

Comment: The Outputs image is the desired output of transposing the data from the inputs image i.e. new sheet.  My dilemma is creating a loop that takes each employees chunk of timecard information and formats it so I have the Name in cell A2 of the new sheet and then each 'violation' count in the columns right of the name.

Comment: Please back up one step, and look at how the Exception Summary was created.  It would be much easier to run a SQL from that original database table, and then pivot it into the required output format.  Don't extend the chain of bad data formatting; start right from the source.

Comment: this data comes from a 3rd party and I do not have access to the DB,  I agree that would be the best practice but in this case I can not modify the query

Comment: I would like some test data.  Please go to https://www.randomlists.com/last-names?qty=20&dup=false   and get some last names to paste over the real names, for say the first 20(?) people.  And Blank-out column D (do not delete the column itself).  And then save the sanitized xls as CSV, Add the file to this question.  I find it hard to convert png files to usable xls.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qhyw4bxaqih78z8/InputSampleExceptionReport.xls?dl=0

Comment: Working with test data... to strip off top 41(or so) rows to isolate employees into another sheet, and then lace the ee-names onto each exception row, and then make pivot in a third sheet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the rough draft, which could use some additional testing with real data.  The pivot columns need to be std width, and their col headings need to be wrapped.  It summarizes names that are duplicates (e.g. Trumpy, Trump).

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub do_TransposeData()

    Const colNewName As Integer = 1
    Const colNameAndExcept As Integer = 2
    Const col4Transpose As Integer = 7
    Const colTally As Integer = 8

    Dim Sheet As Excel.Worksheet, thisSheet As String
    Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    thisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name

    Const wsNewJustEE As String = "NewJustEE"
    Const wsNewPivot As String = "NewPivot"
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = wsNewJustEE Or ws.Name = wsNewPivot Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(ws.Name).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = wsNewJustEE
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = wsNewPivot

    Sheets(wsNewJustEE).Select
    Dim colHeads  As Variant, newRow As Long, newCol As Long
    colHeads = Array("Employee", "NameOrExcept", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "ExTranspose", "ExCount")  '  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    newRow = 1
    For newCol = 1 To 8
        Sheets(wsNewJustEE).Cells(newRow, newCol) = colHeads(newCol)
    Next newCol





    Dim sPriorRowName As String, sThisRowName As String, sSavedName As String
    Dim flagInNames As Boolean, flagInExceptions As Boolean

    Dim nRow As Long, maxRow As Long
    maxRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row


    For nRow = 1 To maxRow

        sPriorRowName = sThisRowName
        sThisRowName = Sheet.Cells(nRow, colNameAndExcept)

        If (flagInNames) Then
            ' need to test from bottom up
            If (sThisRowName = "TOTALS") Then
                flagInExceptions = False
            End If

            If (flagInExceptions And sThisRowName <> "EXCEPTIONS") Then
                newRow = newRow + 1
                For newCol = 1 To 8
                    Sheets(wsNewJustEE).Cells(newRow, newCol) = Sheets(thisSheet).Cells(nRow, newCol)
                Next newCol
                Sheets(wsNewJustEE).Cells(newRow, colNewName) = sSavedName
                Sheets(wsNewJustEE).Cells(newRow, col4Transpose) = "4Transpose"
            End If

            If (sThisRowName = "EXCEPTIONS" And Not flagInExceptions) Then
                sSavedName = sPriorRowName
                flagInExceptions = True
            End If
        End If

        If (sThisRowName = "NAME") Then
            flagInNames = True
        End If

    Next nRow

    Sheets(wsNewJustEE).Select
    Cells.Select
    Sheets(wsNewPivot).Select
    do_Pivot

End Sub

'    Sheets("NewJustEE").Select
'    Cells.Select
'    Sheets.Add
'    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
'        "NewJustEE!R1C1:R65536C8", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
'        TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
'        :=xlPivotTableVersion10
'    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
'    Cells(3, 1).Select
'    Application.Goto Reference:="Macro1"



Sub do_Pivot()

    'Sheets.Add
    'ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "NewPivot"

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "NewJustEE!R1C1:R65536C8", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="NewPivot!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion10
    Sheets("NewPivot").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("ExTranspose")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("ExTranspose")
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("ExCount"), "Count of ExCount", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("ExTranspose")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Count of ExCount")
        .Caption = "Sum of ExCount"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Employee")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("NameOrExcept")  '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Rows("4:4").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 4.86
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt at what I think you may require.  I hope it helps.

```
    Option Explicit


    Const cEnd As String = "grand totals"
    Const cName As String = "name"
    Const cEx As String = "exceptions"
    Const cTot As String = "total"
    Const cID As String = "id"
    Const cTots As String = "totals"

    Const cEA As String = "excused absence"
    Const cLO As String = "late out"
    Const cLI As String = "late in"
    Const cVLO As String = "very late out"
    Const cEI As String = "early in"
    Const cEO As String = "early out"
    Const cMOP As String = "missed out punch"
    Const cUA As String = "unexcused absence"
    Const cBOS As String = "break out of sequence"
    Const cMIP As String = "missed in punch"
    Const cVEI As String = "very early in"
    Const cSB As String = "short break"


    Private Type udtEmployees
        Name As String
        ExcusedAbsence As Integer
        LateOut As Integer
        LateIn As Integer
        VeryLateOut As Integer
        EarlyIn As Integer
        EarlyOut As Integer
        MissedOutPunch As Integer
        UnexcusedAbsence As Integer
        BreakOutOfSequence As Integer
        MissedInPunch As Integer
        VeryEarlyIn As Integer
        ShortBreak As Integer
    End Type

    Private uEmps() As udtEmployees

    Public Sub GetEmployeeData()
        Dim lngI As Long
        Dim lngJ As Long
        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim strGrandTotals As String
        Dim blnEnd As Boolean
        Dim blnMainStart As Boolean
        Dim blnEmpStart As Boolean
        Dim lngCnt As Long
        Dim strB As String
        Dim strD As String
        Dim strH As String

        Dim strSheet As String
        Dim strOutSheet As String

        strSheet = "Sheet1"
        strOutSheet = "Sheet2"

        lngI = 1
        blnEnd = False
        blnMainStart = False
        blnEmpStart = False
        lngCnt = 0
        Do Until blnEnd
            With Worksheets(strSheet)

                strTemp = LCase(Trim(.Cells(lngI, 1).Value))


                If strTemp = cEnd Then
                    blnEnd = True
                Else
                    'Look for NAME(B), ID(D), TOTAL(H) = START NAME LOOK UP.
                    strB = LCase(Trim(.Cells(lngI, 2).Value))
                    strD = LCase(Trim(.Cells(lngI, 4).Value))
                    strH = LCase(Trim(.Cells(lngI, 8).Value))

                    'prevent type mismatch
                    If Len(strH) < 1 Then strH = "0"

                    If (strB = cName) And (strD = cID) And (strH = cTot) Then
                        blnMainStart = True
                    Else
                        If blnMainStart Then
                            If (strB = cEx) And (strH = cTot) And (blnEmpStart = False) Then
                                blnEmpStart = True
                                ReDim Preserve uEmps(0 To lngCnt)
                                'Get the person's name!
                                uEmps(lngCnt).Name = Trim(.Cells(lngI - 1, 2).Value)
                            End If

                            If (strB = cTots) Then
                                blnEmpStart = False
                                lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
                            End If
                            If blnEmpStart Then
                                Select Case strB
                                  Case cEA
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).ExcusedAbsence = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cLO
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).LateOut = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cLI
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).LateIn = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cVLO
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).VeryLateOut = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cEI
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).EarlyIn = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cEO
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).EarlyOut = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cMOP
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).MissedOutPunch = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cUA
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).UnexcusedAbsence = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cBOS
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).BreakOutOfSequence = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cMIP
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).MissedInPunch = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cVEI
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).VeryEarlyIn = CInt(strH)
                                  Case cSB
                                      uEmps(lngCnt).ShortBreak = CInt(strH)
                                  Case Else
                                      'Do nothing, probably a blank!
                                End Select
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
            lngI = lngI + 1
        Loop

        'Write out the Headers
        lngI = 1
        lngJ = 1
        With Worksheets(strOutSheet)
            'First, set Up the columns
            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Excused Absence"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Late Out"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Late In"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Very Late Out"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Early In"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Early Out"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Missed Out Punch"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Unexcused Absence"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Break Out Of Sequence"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Missed In Punch"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Very Early In"

            lngJ = lngJ + 1
            .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = "Short Break"

            'Finally, write out the data.
            lngI = 1
            For lngCnt = 0 To UBound(uEmps)
                lngJ = 1
                lngI = lngI + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).Name
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).ExcusedAbsence
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).LateOut
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).LateIn
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).VeryLateOut
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).EarlyIn
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).EarlyOut
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).MissedOutPunch
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).UnexcusedAbsence
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).BreakOutOfSequence
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).MissedInPunch
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).VeryEarlyIn
                lngJ = lngJ + 1
                .Cells(lngI, lngJ).Value = uEmps(lngCnt).ShortBreak
            Next lngCnt
        End With
    End Sub
```